# 3 images on first line and 3 images on second line in centre of page

Tags: html, css

I would like 3 images on the first line and 3 images on the second line and want them in the middle of the page

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
    ul { 
      list-style: none; 
      font-size: 0; 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      text-align: center; }

    li { display: inline-block; padding: 10px;}

    li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(4) {
      width: 50%;
    }
    li:nth-child(4) { text-align: right; }
    li:nth-child(2) { text-align: left; }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
<li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

there are many ways to do it, for example:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d6wn79pv/4/

or

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d6wn79pv/9/

Answer (score 1):

with use of **flexbox**:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li{
  width:30%;
  margin:3px auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
ul { 
  list-style: none; 
  font-size: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  text-align: center; }


li {
  width: 31%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:3px;
}



</style>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>  
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>  
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>  
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your css if all the `nth-child` are the same you could just have `li` and it would make your CSS simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using flex

```
<ul class="here">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" /></li>
</ul>
```

```
.here{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.here li {
    width: 32%;
}
.here li img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Change the `.here` `width` to auto resize the content